# Comparing string to list of objects with repr

Tags: python-3.x, repr

If I have a class called Person, and this class contains the name, age, etc. of each person, if I fill a list with the Person class I want to check if a name is in the list without creating a new list of just the names. If I use **repr** and return repr(self.name), I can print the list and have it return a list of the names of each person in the list. If I then check if "steve" is in the list it returns False. I am guessing this is because it is comparing "steve" to each class, not the class **repr**. Is there a way to do this without creating a new list?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.name)

people = [Person('steve', 25), Person('dan', 30),Person('heather', 19)]
print(people)
print('steve' in people)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(p.name == 'steve' for p in people)
#True
```

...and a fail test:

```
any(p.name == 'bob' for p in people)
#False
```

---

However, to be able to use `in`, you need to define `__eq__`, not `__repr__`:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __eq__(self, s):
        return s == self.name
```

and now it works as intended:

```
'steve' in people
#True

'bob' in people
#False
```

Comment: Probably want to modify that __eq__ to something more like `return (s == self.name) if isinstance(s, str) else super().__eq__(s)` so that you don't make it impossible to compare two `Person` objects

Comment: Also, this `__eq__` solution, while very pretty (and honestly a good idea), will result in very slow performance, especially if you need to look for multiple names in the list. If these `in` checks are an important/frequent part of the program or the number of `Person`s might get large, it'll become necessary to use a hash- or tree-based data structure

Comment: A hybrid solution would be to implement a `__hash__` that returns `hash(self.name)`, then that combined with this modified `__eq__` function would allow you to just create a set of `Person` objects and do `'steve' in set(persons)`

Comment: The lists aren't going to get very large so I'm not to worried about search speed at the moment but I will take this into consideration should this need to be scaled up significantly. Thanks!

Comment: @scnerd Your first point is unnecessary, `__eq__` is invoked in both objects anyway.

Comment: @scnerd And whilst a set sol may be more efficient for big lists, it does add an extra layer of complexity for the OP who is only after a simple, working solution.

Comment: @JoeIddon you're correct, I didn't see that that'd happen (took me a few minutes with a terminal to figure out why it worked), very slick solution. Still recommend implementing `__hash__`, in part to make the object more useful, and also so that hash-based techniques will work out of the box for both string- and object-based searches

Comment: @scnerd No problem :), I like your set sol anyway, so +1 to that :p

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way probably is to just do this manually:

```
steve_in_people = any('steve' == repr(person) for person in people)
```

You could also use a bloom filter to quickly determine if 'steve' *isn't* in your list, but there's no way to know for sure without checking the list. You could also use something like a B-Tree to perform this check very quickly (worst case would be something like O(m) where m is the length of the string you're looking for).

If you don't want fancy data structures and would prefer to be pythonic... well then, use a set, which will give you very high-performance `in` checks (virtually constant-time):

```
names = {repr(person) for person in people}
steve_in_people = 'steve' in names
```

---

@JoeIddon makes a good point about modifying the class to easily support this behavior. I'll suggest one further improvement:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __eq__(self, s):
        return s == self.name

    # This will allow you to quickly find this object in a set using its name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

Now you can just create a set of `Person` objects and search into it using a name string:

```
person_set = set(all_person_objects)
steve_in_people = 'steve' in person_set
```